# What happens if an android app, which creates database, is then uninstalled?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, uninstallation

I developed and install an android application which create a sqlite database.
If I uninstall this app the database will be automatically dropped?

Comment: I presume it will be removed if it resides within the applications directory. Try it and let us know the results.

Comment: As the answered state - if your DB is installed in your application directory structure, then it is likely to be deleted. I would suggest that if you **want** to delete the database than do it as part of your un-installation process. I would not rely on the DB being dropped automatically.

Comment: I thought it was not a question so trivial. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YES....
After create Database it will be located at `data/data/YourPackage/mydatabase.db`.
when you install application on Emulator or Phone then it will be visible in File Explorer.
This `mydatabase.db` file will be deleted when you uninstall your application but if you reinstall this application then this database file again created and will be available in your private folder.

**Edit**

Suppose you want to store some value in Database([SQLite](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html)), For this you need to create one java class like `MySQLiteHelper` and then you can simply write your value in database.
If you uninstall you application then your value and database will be deleted but if you again reinstall your application then your database again created but previous value will be lost.

Answer (score 2):

The database is a file in private storage ( /data/data/{package.name}/databases/db.file )
when you uninstall an app the /data/data/{package.name}/ is deleted, either the user associated to the app is.

Answer (score 0):

I think so, database will be dropped with all files in your app's private folder :)