# Delete all record from the data base

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am working on a project on android where thousands of tables exist.Unfortunately I do not have fresh data base so what can I do to delete all record from all tables. i am using sqlite database .If it is possible please tell me.

Comment: Uninstall app from device or emulator & run again.

Comment: It will uninstall the app and also removed the db. So next time whenever you will install your app again, it will create fresh db again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the entire rows/data from table, then it's better to drop the table and recreate it. This is the usual convention and for this reason *SqLiteOpenHelper* has *onCreate()* and *onUpgrade()* method which creates table or upgrades it, when table is dropped, or database version is changed

For **deleting/dropping** table, the code fragment is

```
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + YOUR_TABLE);
```

Check the first answer for reference [What happens if an android app, which creates database, is then uninstalled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13067585/what-happens-if-an-android-app-which-creates-database-is-then-uninstalled)